# SharePoint Calendar App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I have a SharePoint site at my job which has about 7 categories(apps) within the site. One of my sites which has unique access (only certain people can see), I would like to add a calendar. Is this possible?  Or maybe I could say, can you have an app within an app? Hope I am making sense

Comment: I think you are confused with app vs site. We can't have an app within an app while we can have many apps inside a site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create more than one calendar (app) in your SharePoint site and SharePoint sub-site.
If it requires 'unique access' were only a few can view and edit, create within the site with 'unique access'.
If it can or needs to be viewed by many, but edited by a few, create at the top level of the site.  Then edit the permissions to create a different permission set from the top level site.

Answer (score -1):

Create calendar within your site with unique permission. Go to advance settings of the Calendar List and setup permissions. See below screenshot from advanced settings window. Hope it helps.
[image: ![advanced settings (Read)]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5fhb.png)